# Create scaffolded item with Powershell

Tags: c#, t4, scaffolding

In our project we have far more than 200 model classes where we have to write a web api Controller for most of them.
So I tried to generate them automatically with a template and Powershell.
I tried to use TextTransform.exe

```
TextTransform.exe -a !!ModelTypeName!CustomerModel -a !!ControllerName!CustomerController -a !!ContextTypeName!WebContext c:\Temp\Controller.cs.t4
```

but then always get the Exception
error : A processor named 'ScaffoldingAssemblyLoader' could not be found for the directive named 'ScaffoldingAssembly'. The transformation will not be run.

> The following Exception was thrown: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Failed to load directive processor ScaffoldingAssemblyLoader.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CommandLine.CommandLineHost.ResolveDirectiveProcessor(String
>   processorName)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessCustomDirectives(ITextTemplatingEngineHost
>   host, TemplateProcessingSession session, IEnumerable`1
>   directivesToBeProcessed)

Can anyone tell me how to generate our scaffolded items programatically?